# HandleRequirementAsync not being called when using authorization in Hot Chocolate

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, asp.net-authorization, hotchocolate

Hi,

I am trying to implement policy-based authorization in a Hot Chocolate `graphql` server.
I am looking at their [documentation](https://hotchocolate.io/docs/authorization) and also referring to [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

What I want to achieve

I want that `HandleRequirementAsync()` will be called whenever a `User query` is being called.

What I've done

1. I register authorization and the `User Policy` in `ConfigureServices`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy",
                policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserRequirement()));
            });


            services.AddSingleton<Query>();

            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserAuthorizationHandler>();

            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IUserRepo), typeof(UserRepo));
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IBookRepository), typeof(BookRepository));

            services.AddGraphQL(
                SchemaBuilder.New()
                    .AddAuthorizeDirectiveType()
                    .AddType<UserType>()
                    .AddType<BookType>()
                    .AddQueryType<Query>());
        }
```

2. I have the `User requirement class` and the `handler`

```
 public class UserAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserRequirement, IResolverContext>
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public UserAuthorizationHandler([Service] IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserRequirement requirement,
            IResolverContext resource)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class UserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
    }
```

3. I declared one field to require the policy authorization.

```
    public class UserType
        : ObjectType<User>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<User> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(t => t.Name).Type<NonNullType<StringType>>().Authorize("UserPolicy");
            descriptor.Field(t => t.Id).Type<NonNullType<StringType>>();
        }
    }
```

#### The problem

When running this code. I expect that the `HandleRequirementAsync` will be called. This method should always succeed. However, when requesting for user. What actually happens is the the method is not called and the request is immediately denied with this following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The current user is not authorized to access this resource.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "user",
        "name"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "AUTH_NOT_AUTHENTICATED"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had an alike problem. In my case I had to ensure that in

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

I had

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

first and **then**

```
app.UseWebSockets()
                .UseGraphQL("/graphql")
                .UsePlayground("/graphql")
                .UseVoyager("/graphql");
```